cannot import name 'split_torch_state_dict_into_shards' from 'huggingface_hub'
I've been using LLAMA 2 for research for a few months now and I import as follows:
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
device = torch.device("cuda")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",token = "token_key",torch_dtype="auto")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",token = "token_key", torch_dtype="auto", load_in_4bit=True)

It has always worked. However, today it is showing the following error:
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.llama.modeling_llama because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
Failed to import transformers.generation.utils because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'split_torch_state_dict_into_shards' from 'huggingface_hub' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/init.py)
Recreated the Hugging Face token, but it didn't work. I am using Google Colab and Kaggle Notebook.

The error you're encountering is due to the split_torch_state_dict_into_shards function not being available in huggingface-hub version < 0.23.0.
This function is included starting from version 0.23.0.
To resolve this issue, update the huggingface-hub library to version 0.23.0 or later
Also please install accelerate:
pip install accelerate==0.31.0

here is a git link: https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/discussions/14605

Thank You. Additionally, I had to adjust Accelerate as well, but worker.

still getting this error with 0.26+

@Jacksonkr please try pip install accelerate==0.31.0

Unfortunately that didn't help. cached_download is no longer a package: https://huggingface.co/api/models/cached_download/revision/main
